# Azure Ad Enterprise App Test Token is getting replaced on save

Tags: azure-active-directory, scim

I am using Azure SCIM for user provisioning in my application. I was using a token generated by my application. Now I want to switch back to the test token of Azure.

But the problem I am facing is:
When I am removing the old token and do a test connection, at my application I am getting a test token (JWT). But as soon as I save and test the connection, my application is getting the older token.

I don't see any caching level setting in my Azure's enterprise app.

I have tried changing browsers, sign in and sign out etc. But it switches to the old token as soon as I save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

If clearing the value and saving isn't working, I'd assume it isn't possible to revert back to the AAD-generated test token. You can delete the job via MS Graph API (HTTP DELETE to /jobs under the /synchronization APIs) or create a new provisioning job on a new non-gallery application to get a clean slate.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the steps suggested by you for deleting the job from MS Graph API. But we tried new non-gallery app, same behavior with new app too.